# What causes overtime in the final round?

Tags: kirbys-dream-buffet

In Kirby's Dream Buffet, sometimes the final round will go into overtime before bonus strawberries are awarded. What determines if the final round goes into overtime?

Answer (score 1):

My speculation comes from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq_kvKQCC8s).
It appears that, when the timer is about to run out, the pink Kirby was 2nd while the blue one was 1st. The frame I took is from the instant in which pink Kirby gets first, probably equalizing the blue one.

So overtime should begin when at least 2 Kirby have the same (or very similar) strawberries count.

[image]